# Nested aggregation in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I do nested aggregation in data.table. For example I'd like to get the percentage of the different gears by cyl.

```
library(data.table)
a <- as.data.table(mtcars)
a[,{
  n_cyl=.N
  .SD[,.(n_cyl,N_cyl_gear=.N,div1=N_cyl_gear/n_cyl),by=gear]
  },by=cyl]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use chaining:

```
# the percentage of the different gears by cyl. 
a[, .N, keyby = .(cyl, gear)
  ][, .(perc = N/sum(N), gear), by = cyl]

   cyl       perc gear
1:   4 0.09090909    3
2:   4 0.72727273    4
3:   4 0.18181818    5
4:   6 0.28571429    3
5:   6 0.57142857    4
6:   6 0.14285714    5
7:   8 0.85714286    3
8:   8 0.14285714    5
```

Alternative format:

```
a[, .N, by = .(cyl, gear)
  ][, .(perc = N/sum(N), gear = gear), by = cyl
    ][, dcast(.SD, cyl ~ paste0("gear", gear), value.var = "perc", fill = 0)]

   cyl      gear3     gear4     gear5
1:   4 0.09090909 0.7272727 0.1818182
2:   6 0.28571429 0.5714286 0.1428571
3:   8 0.85714286 0.0000000 0.1428571
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars$id <- 1:nrow(mtcars)
mtcars%>% group_by(cyl,gear) %>% summarise(freq=n_distinct(id)) %>% mutate(share=freq/sum(freq))
```